# Wordpress Installation Bug?

Tags: wordpress, installation

Anyone has experience installing CiviCRM in Wordpress? I tried to follow the installation guide but I come with this problem, Google doesn't offer much help. It comes with an error in the database name "The database name provided is not valid. Please use only 0-9, a-z, A-Z, _ and - as characters in the name."
Any help or direction to get help will be appreciated.[image: Error when running the installer]

[image: I edited an added the db name]

Comment: Can you make sure you database only includes name, number, underscore and hypen chars only?

Comment: What is your db name?  That's the key piece of information in the screenshot but its redacted!

Comment: Hi Pradeep, the db name is only numbers.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, Civi requires it to have at least one letter (lower case or upper doesn't matter).

See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.29.1/CRM/Core/DAO.php#L2992